# Capture register value at specific instance in Verilog

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, vlsi

I created two always blocks in Verilog. In one always block, one bit register variable is flipping and in other always block, a counter variable is running. Now when counter will reach to a specific value I want to read the status of another loop variable. But couldn't understand the correct way to do it. Please help. Thank you for your time.

**Verilog code:**

```
module test1(
    input enb,
    input shift,
    input customClk,
    output out,
    output intr,
    input reset
);

reg [31:0] counter;
reg temp_out;
reg intr;
reg out;

always @ (posedge reset) begin
    counter <= 32'b0;
    temp_out <= 1'b0;
    intr <= 1'b0;
end

always @ (posedge customClk) begin
    counter <= counter + 1'b1;
    if(counter==5000) begin
        counter <= 32'b0;
        out = temp_out;
        intr = 1'b1;
    end
end

always @ (*) begin
    temp_out <= ~temp_out;
end

endmodule
```

**Testbench code:**

```
module test1_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg enb;
    reg shift;
    reg customClk;
    reg out;
    reg intr;
    reg reset;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    test1 uut (
        .enb(enb), 
        .shift(shift), 
        .customClk(customClk),
        .out(out),
        .intr(intr),
        .reset(reset)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        enb = 0;
        shift = 0;
        customClk = 0;
        reset=0;

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;
        
        reset =1;
        
      if(intr) begin
            $display("%b",out);
        end
        
    end
    
    always #5 customClk = ~customClk;
      
endmodule
```

**Simulation output:**

[image: ISim Output]

Comment: So why did you comment // out = temp_out. Isn't that what you want

Comment: Actually I will print the output there but I am receiving impedance in simulation for the output registers like "intr". Also out = temp_out; showing error but if i give assign out = temp_out; then I will not be able to control specific instance. What should I need to change in code. Thank you

Comment: @DipnarayanDas if a central part of your code can't be synthesized, shouldn't that raise a red flag that you need to fix that first?

Comment: In the Verilog code, shouldn't that be reg [31:0] counter; otherwise it is 1-bit wide

Comment: Good catch by Martin. Didn't notice that. By the way were you able to sort out? @DipnarayanDas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't follow the general coding guidelines, for example:

1. You are using blocking assignments for registers inside the clocked `always @(posedge ..)` block. It has to be non-blocking assignment like for eg: `counter <= 32'b0 ;`
2. You have a combinational loop in the combinational `always @(*)` block, which has undefined behaviour. Shouldn't you use a clocked `always @(posedge ..)` block there as well, if you are toggling the bit `temp_out`?
3. The output port `out` is currently of `wire` type by default. You have to explicitly mention it as `reg` if you intended to drive it inside the always block and read `temp_out` like: `out <= temp_out ;`
4. Initial blocks are used only on test benches, not on designs. They are not generally synthesisable by ASIC/FPGA tools. Use a reset signal instead to initialize registers.

**UPDATE**:

*Declaration of `count` looks wrong. It should be `reg [31 : 0] count`*.

Comment: Hello, I want the undefined behavior. When the counter will reach at specific value, I want to get random status from that flipping bit. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Randomisation? That should be asked as a different question as it deviates from the intention of your current question. You asked what was the error in reading `temp_out` in the first always block...I have answered. Hope this answer helped.

Comment: Yes definitely. The answer was really helped. I will post another question with the randomness query. Can you please identify where I am going wrong, that's why getting impedance in output? Thank you